# Error While giving Git Repo URL in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I am trying to configure Freestyle Project in Jenkins.
First of all, I am running docker on my VirtualBox and inside the docker I have jenkins container.
On the same VM I have my bare git repository.
I am trying to give the repo URL while configuring it but it gives me following errors:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h name@127.0.0.1:/home/name/RemoteGit HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I don't understand now what to do next can someone help me out with this. Also I could not find .ssh inside my jenkins container so that I can give my key to it...

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is trying to get your repository through SSH on localhost but it looks like you don't have an SSH server.

You should refer to the local path of your repository by using the `file://` protocol: `file:///home/name/RemoteGit`.

BTW, be sure that Jenkins as the right permissions to access this folder.

Comment: With this solution or another? Please mark as resolved in the first case or share your solution in the second one.